# Panel not theming

Tags: 15.10, themes, icon-themes

I'm running ubuntu 15.10 and my panel doesn't change theme anymore. It remains the default theme. In addition to this I my icons will no longer change icon pack, and remain the default. This is quite frustrating and I cannot fix it.

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

To solve this just type: 
`ALT + F2` then type `unity --reload`

Alternatively you can do this through the terminal, but be sure to leave the window open for a while, as otherwise it will fail to load all UI elements.